# Typescript array spread operator type safety

Tags: typescript

I have a relatively simple piece of code, and I don't know why this does not produce any errors:

```js
interface ITest {
  value: number;
};

let x: ITest[] = [{  value: 10 }];
console.log(x);

x = { ...x };
console.log(x);

x = { ...[{value: 10}] }
console.log(x);
```

which produces:

```
[{
  "value": 10
}] 
------------------------
{
  "0": {
    "value": 10
  }
} 
------------------------
{
  "0": {
    "value": 10
  }
}
```

The second and third assignment to `x` are clearly not of type `ITest[]`.
I think it has to do with the spread operator or with the fact that `[]` inside the `{}` creates some sort of weird mapping type.

How does this work?
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyyAbnADYCuEAXMiJQLYBG0A3AQL4cHkS4APOhmxgA2gF1kAXmRi8xMlVrIAjAAZknCRwQB7EFj18AdOT0BzABQCAlDwEz8yE68fcC%20w8YhnLN%20wICR1kFVxN5JWo6DW0tTwMjU3NrOw4gA)

Comment: Technically, everything is fine, since arrays are objects, and since the keys are numbers after the spread the result type is an array

Comment: I am not so sure about that. Calling `x.length()` after the third assignment results in `undefined`

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment on why this question was downvoted. If there's something wrong with it, I'm happy to fix it.

Comment: (I didn't downvote). oh yeah, you are right, the length is missing. There is a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726)

Comment: ah thanks, I'm going to read up on that. Curiously, `x[0]` produces the correct result. Before reading the issue, I suspect it has something to do with creating a mapped type?

Comment: Well, I don't know the deep details but the part I know is something like that.  Typescript treats `x` as an object literal. So it allows specifying a property named that the array can have `0,1,2 ... and length`. `{ ...x }` will assign the property named 0 which is fine here. you can also add a property named `length` but it won't allow any other property name since the array doesn't have it.

Comment: @Hafnernuss Initially `x` has one element, which means that it has `0` key, when you spread it becomes a key for the object, so everything is valid there

Comment: `x[0]` works because `0` is a property of `x`, nothing curious about that. Calling any array function results in an error though. After reading the github issue for a bit, this seems to be a typing issue when using the spread operator.

Comment: @wonderflame If you take a look at my example below, you will see, that the TS type checker rejects the an object with a "0" property if typed manually. It gets only confused if the spread operator is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually seems to be an error of the type checker on an edge case. Somehow the type checker does not realise the mismatching type of the outer array if the spread operator is used and the inner type is correct.
Also the following examples show that it works under other circumstances correctly: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyyAbnADYCuEAXMiJQLYBG0A3AQL4cHkS4APOhmxgA2gF1kAXmRi8xMlVrIAjAAZknCRwQB7EFj18AdOT0BzABQCAlDwEz8yE68fdiAek-09yMACeAA4oCAAWEAgA1sjQUHpQADTIzJS4wFjIcCDIeswAVpHphpBwACa5MFk5cFBQcAEE+obGEGaWNvYEBI6yCq4m8krUdBraWl4+IH6BIcjhkTFxCcmp6ZnZuQVFyKA4EOWV1Vl1DU0GRqbm1nYOTgoAROoPdHjDKmNabJP+waER0VidRWu0y+jqRXOLSuHVu3V6zieL3w71G6k4yQGki+P2mvzmC0ByySKTSoOOeUKCGK+0Oeiqm1q9UazUubWunTusjEKIoIzU6OQOh+vnx-0WQPiJIy8wSUEhrNa7RuXSAA)

```
x = { "0": {value: 10} };  // type check error, is correct
console.log(x);

x = { "0": {value: 10}, ...[] };  // no type check error, but is an object instead of an array
console.log(x);

x = [ {value: 10} ];  //  no type check error, is correct
console.log(x);
```

#### Update

This is a known [issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726) (it is not quite clear at the initial statements of the issue but further down there are multiple accounts of this behavior.)